# How to select all columns from joomla table?

Tags: php, joomla

I want select all the columns from jos_content table and one column from jos_categories table in Joomla.For That I used following query:

```
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true);
 $query->select($db->quoteName(array('c.*', 'cat.alias')))
       ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'c'))
       ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories', 'cat'))
       ->where($db->quoteName('c.catid') .'='.$db->quoteName('cat.id'));
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

But when I used the above query it shows following error:

```
 1054 - Unknown column 'c.*' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT `c`.`*`,`cat`.`alias` FROM `jos_content` AS `c`,`jos_categories` AS `cat` WHERE `c`.`catid`=`cat`.`id`
```

If I used ' c.id ' (or few column names) Instead of 'c.*' it's working perfectly.

How to solve this problem.Please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try removing `$db->quoteName` from the select statement?

Comment: You should be using a `join` clause ;)

Comment: @DavidePastore I too has the similar prob, as OP, and your suggestion helped, but then how can I quote the identifier names? Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try to read [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Constructing_SQL_queries)?

Answer (score 2):

Your code working:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('c.*', 'cat.alias'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'c'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__categories', 'cat'))
->where($db->quoteName('c.catid') .'='.$db->quoteName('cat.id'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

With a JOIN instead:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('c.*', 'cat.alias'))
->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'c'))
->join('INNER','#__categories as cat ON cat.id = c.catid')
->where($db->quoteName('c.catid') .'='.$db->quoteName('cat.id'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```